# Increase network traffic between worker nodes through apache spark's shuffle process

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shuffle

I am trying to write a (wordcount) program to simulate a use case where the network traffic would be very high because of spark's shuffle process. I have a 3 node apache spark cluster (2 cores each, 8GB RAM each) configured with 1 master and 2 workers. I processed a 5GB file for wordcount and was able to see a network traffic between 2 worker nodes raise up to 1GB in 10-15 mins. I am looking for a way where i could increase the traffic between nodes raise up to atleast 1GB within 30s-60s. The inefficiency of the program or best practices doesn't matter in my current use case as I am just trying to simulate traffic.

This is the program i have written

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("LetterCount-GroupBy-Map"))
val x = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(t => t.split(" "))
val y = x.map(w => (w.charAt(0),w))
val z = y.groupByKey().mapValues(n => n.size)
z.collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

More shuffled data can be generated by doing operations which do not combine data very well on each node. For eg: In the code you have written, the groupby will combine the common keys ( or do groupby locally). Instead choose a high cardinality of keys (in above example its 26 only). In addition, the size of values after the map operation can be increased. In your case, its the text line. You might want to put a very long string of values for each key.

Apart from this, if you take 2 different files/tables and apply join on some parameter, it will also cause shuffling.

Note: Am assuming the contents does not matter. You are only interested in generating highly shuffled data.